# Moving average MA(1) coefficient estimation

Tags: mathematical-optimization, time-series

I am new to mathematica, I have some simulated a moving average, MA(1), data and I want to estimate the coefficients, theta, of it using Maximum likelihood estimation or log likelihood. Can someone help me with this on how to achieve this on Mathematica. Thank you.

I have 2 pre-defined parameters:

μ: unknown (pre-defined)

σ<sup>2</sup> :unknown (pre-defined)

θ: unkown (pre-defined)

[image: MA(1) simulation]

w <sub>t</sub> is zero centered white noise.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor. To get started, 1) take the [introductory tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the [gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge,

Comment: 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the [checkmark sign](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.